# octobercms database query cache not working

Tags: php, mysql, caching, octobercms

In one of my pages I perform a database query like so..

```
function onStart()
{
    $this['numz'] = Db::table('backend_users')->select('id')->count();
}
```

This works as expected and returns me a value that I can use in the page like so

```
There are a total of {{ numz }} ppl.
```

Now according to [this](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/query#caching-queries), we should be able to do ...

```
function onStart()
{
    $this['numz'] = Db::table('backend_users')->select('id')->remember(10)->count();
}
```

However when ever I try this, I get the following error;

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::remember()

Any idea what the issue is or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has now been fixed in build 398+.

https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2639